# Solve the differential equation $\frac{y''^2 - y'y''}{y'^2} = {1\over x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got stuck on this differential equation. Most of the equation I solved has degree of highest derivative 1. But in this equation, degree of $y''$ is 2. Can anyone help me or give me some hint so I can solve it? I really appreciate.

> Solve this differential equation:
>   $$\frac{y''^2 - y'y''}{y'^2} = {1\over x^2}$$

Comment: The left hand side is the derivative of a simple expression.

Comment: Take $Y = \log(y') \implies Y'(Y'-1) = \frac{1}{x^2}$. Solve for $Y'$, integrate to get $Y$, exponentiate to get $y' = e^{Y}$ and integrate again to get $y$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: Can you please explain clearer? Which function are you mentioning?

Comment: When I wrote my comment I wasn't wearing my glasses and I missed two $'$s (I thought the left hand side was $-(y'/y)'$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$ \frac{y''^2 - y'y''}{y'^2} = \left(\frac{y''}{y'}\right)^2 - \frac{y''}{y'} $$

Let $u = \frac{y''}{y'}$, this becomes
$$u^2 - u =\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$ \left( u - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{4}$$
$$ u = \frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{4}}$$

Since $$\frac{y''}{y'} = \frac{d}{dx}\ln(y')$$

This gives
$$y' = \exp\left( \int u(x)\,dx \right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution.